# Lie algebra and BPS stats

Tags: mathematical-physics

i would know   what is a charges Lattice and  the relationship between it and roots lattice ? and if there is relationship between  mutation of quiver and weyl group? and how the PBS stats correspond to weight in in a given representation?

Comment: What do you mean by "charge lattice"? Are you refering to BPS monopoles when mention BPS states?